# Unsatisfied linkerror aarch64 Samsung Galaxy S6

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, java-native-interface

Hi I have been trying to test my code on my Samsung Galaxy S6, but it keeps crashing because of an Unsatisfied linkerror. Here is the error message:

```
AndroiddRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.example.ericagredo.marvinproject, PID: 14982
                                                                                  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native library (com/sun/jna/android-aarch64/libjnidispatch.so) not found in resource path (.)
                                                                                      at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:866)
                                                                                      at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:826)
                                                                                      at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:140)
                                                                                      at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:481)
                                                                                      at com.emotiv.iedk.Edk.<clinit>(Edk.java:15)
                                                                                      at com.example.ericagredo.marvinproject.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374)
                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2879)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:182)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

I am using jna.jar as a library and I believe that's where the problem is stemming from. When I go into the folders, there is no folder named android-aarch64 and I am not sure how to get it.

Here are the folders in jna.jar: 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAYnP.png)

Comment: It would appear that the library you are using wasn't built for devices with the aarch64 architecture. What other folders are there?

Comment: I edited the post for you to see.

Comment: Very well. Checkout the screenshot

Comment: Alright, yeah. You are using some emotiv library? Notice that none of those folder start with "android"? Where did you get that JAR from, and did it claim to support Android?

Comment: I got it from the emotiv SDK, but I'm assuming it's outdated? Where do I get a JAR that supports the phone then?

Comment: Try to see if you can run one of their Android examples. https://github.com/Emotiv/community-sdk/tree/master/examples/Android

Comment: Interesting, before the examples did not work and now they do. I think i'll fix my project based off the example then

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not entirely sure you need a JAR file.

In the [Emotiv Android examples](https://github.com/Emotiv/community-sdk/tree/master/examples/Android), there is this Gradle dependency.

```
compile 'com.emotiv.sdk:community:3.3.+@aar'
```

Answer (score 0):

it mostly happens when you use native library and there isn't support in Android Gradle for native code yet 
for native libraries try this

1. make a folder name  "jniLibs "
2. add these sub folders one by one

   - armeabi
   - armeabi-v7a
   - mips
   - x86

put  your library into these folders  and rebuild your project

Hope this will help